# Firebase/Firestore data is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do a simple firestore query, using a where clause inside firebase cloud functions but I get `foo.data is not a function`.

```
exports.uploadList = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
 try {
    let foo = await db.collection('users').where('appToken', '==', 'xxxx').get()
    if (foo) {
      return res.status(200).send({ foo: foo.data() })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error)
  }
})
```

The response I get is an empty object `{}`, if I remove the try/catch block I can see an error in cloud functions log `foo.data is not a function`.

I read that `where()` is optional so also tried `db.collection('users').get()`, same result.

I can query using `db.collection().doc().get()` and it works fine but no way to find a document by a field value. `set` and `update` also work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bit of code you've written:

```
db.collection('users').where('appToken', '==', 'xxxx').get()
```

returns a promise that resolves with a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) type object (not a [DocumentSnapshot](http://DocumentSn)).  As you can see from linked API documentation, QuerySnapshot doesn't have a `data()` method like DocumentSnapshot does.  That's because the SDK doesn't know how many documents are in the result set ahead of time.  So, you'll have to iterate the results.  One way to do that is with the `docs` property on QuerySnapshot, which is just an array of [QueryDocumentSnapshots](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QueryDocumentSnapshot.html) that match the query constraints.  Or use its `forEach` method.

There are plenty of examples in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).